# Python Regex; why does ignorecase change something?

Tags: python, regex

here is a regex : `[,-_ ]+titi[,-_ ]+`.

Here's a test case : `"tata - titi _ Toto"`

The regex is meant to capture `"titi"` plus optional delimitating characters, including blankspace, so that I can then change `"tata - titi _ Toto"` to `"tata Toto"`.

I can't for the life of me figure what is capturing the T of Toto, and doesn't capture it when going case insensitive.

Comment: Escape the hyphen.

Comment: `r'[,_ -]+titi[,_ -]+'` (keep unescaped hyphen at first or last position in a character class)

Comment: You've supplied your regex and your test case, which is great, but please could you also give the expected and actual results? Also, https://regex101.com/ is very useful when you're debugging regexes

Comment: Thanks for the hyphen; didn't see my mistake.